# Can the functions $\|y-A x\|_1$ or $\|y-A x\|_\infty$ ever be affine over $x \geq 0$ given certain structure on $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, matrix-norms

#### Question:

Any valid norm is convex. Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am wondering under what conditions on $y$ and $A$ (if any) the functions
$$
\|y- Ax\|_1
$$
and
$$
\| y- A x \|_\infty,
$$
are **affine** over $x \geq 0$.

I am only interested in the non-trivial case, i.e., where  $A$ is *not* a non-negative/non-positive matrix.

#### Assumptions (*optional*, if helpful) :

- You can assume that $\mathsf{sign}(y) \in \{\pm 1\}^n$ is known.
- You can assume that $A \succeq 0$.

#### What I have tried:

For the $\ell_1$ norm, from the dual norm characization:
$$
\| y - Ax \|_1 = \sup_{u : \|u\|_\infty \leq 1 } u^\top(y - Ax),
$$
I think that the norm is affine over $x \geq 0$ if
$$
A^\top \textsf{sign}(y) \leq 0,
$$
but I'm uncertain if this is correct. I also don't know if similar conditions hold for $\| y- A x\|_\infty$.

Comment: When you say affine, do you mean of the form $f(x) = Px + Q$? If $y = Ay'$ then $f(y' + x) = f(y' - x)$ should be a pretty restrictive condition.